# Can we represent a limit using divergent series that satisfy certain conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can we represent a limit using divergent series that satisfy certain conditions?

Question 1:

I want to find an equivalence for a divergent series $S$ (which has a Ramanujan summation equal to $-1/12$) to the limit as x approaches positive infinity of $g(x)$, where g(x) is defined as $g(x) = x(x+1)/2$?

Solution 1:

I can say that there is an equivalence between $S$ and $\lim_{{x \to +\infty}} g(x)$, where $g(x) = \frac{x \cdot (x + 1)}{2}$.

Because we have:

$S_n = 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k = \frac{n \cdot (n + 1)}{2}$

And $\lim_{{x \to +\infty}} g(x) = \lim_{{n \to +\infty}} S_n$ , I'm not sure in this case if it's equal or just equivalent, but in both cases, it solves the problem.

So $S=1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots=\lim_{{x \to +\infty}} g(x)$ with $S$ having a Ramanujan summation equal to -1/12.

And I can choose an infinite number of other $S_n$ that will be equivalent but with Ramanujan summations that are not equal to -1/12.

For example, $S_n = \frac{n^2 \cdot (n + 1)}{2(n - 1)}$

So $\lim_{{x \to +\infty}} g(x) $~ $\lim_{{n \to +\infty}} S_n$, but $S_n$ would not have a Ramanujan summation equal to $-1/12$.

Question 2:

$ M(v) = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}}$ with  $m_0 = 10000$ ,$c = 3 \times 10^8$.

So I think we can do the same thing to find the equivalent series S for $\lim_{v \to c} M(v)$ by transforming it into $\lim_{v \to c-} M(v) = \lim_{{x \to \infty}} g(x)$.

I want to find an equivalence for a divergent series $S$ (which has a Ramanujan summation equal to $m_0$ ) to the limit as $x$ approaches positive infinity of $g(x)$?

Find solution 2?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: tnks Is the image not clear there are all the details?
You wanted me to put it in text?

Comment: @Gary Is it clear now?

Comment: Those artifical summations usually have no real merit and it is hard to justify why the chosen method is the "natural" way to assign a value to the divergent series. I do not know the history , but I also doubt that Ramanujan dealt with such assignments. He is famous for other series , for example the baffling series converging to $\pi$.

Comment: Unfortunately , he claimed that some god told him this solution , instead of telling the world how he arrived at such results. I am pretty sure that he found it in a natural way and not from some god. That is however a different story.

Comment: Here in this link there are the mathematical methods which justify this sum 1+2+3..=-1/12    http://www.numdam.org/item/MSM_1954__128__1_0.pdf

Comment: The equation $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$ is utter nonsense. $-1/12$ is not the value of the sum, but the value of the analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta-function, it does not coincide with the sum outside some specific region.